# SpringBoot - Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I was trying for CRUD services using springboot with mongodb.

Getting error while running main application.

`ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.cts.eaution.impl.ProductServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Controller class :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/e-auction/api/v1/seller/")
public class ProductController {
    
    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl;
    
/*  @Autowired
    public ProductRepository productRepository;
    */
    @GetMapping("/show-bids")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        System.out.println("Hello Product...");
        return productServiceImpl.findAll();
        //return productRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    
}
```

ServiceImpl class :

```
class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Product> findAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Service interface :

```
@Service
public interface ProductService {
    
    List<Product> findAll();

}
```

Repository interface :

```
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {

}
```

Pom xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.7.5</version> -->
        <version>2.6.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cts</groupId>
    <artifactId>eauction</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eauction</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried multiple option by adding annotation like (service, repository, component, componentscan) non of this solve the problem.

application properties :
#server
server.port=8082

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=productdb
```

Full Error logs :

`Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.cts.eauction.repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place the `@Service` annotation on the implementation and not on the interface in order to make it autodetected by the component scan. Like this:

```
@Service
class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Product> findAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Also you should ask for a bean of the interface type and not the implementation in your controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/e-auction/api/v1/seller/")
public class ProductController {
    
    @Autowired
    public ProductService productService;
}
```

This way you can have different implementations of the same interface, also you should not use field injection unless you have a good reason to use it.

Comment: In this case , am getting error like `nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.cts.eauction.repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is`

Comment: @Karthikeyan that is a separate error, but I'll try to help, can you add your properties file to the question? Also can you add the full error message to the question?

Comment: updated full error message with application properties file

Comment: @Karthikeyan I am not sure, but can you try removing the trailing spaces after your db name in your properties file? This indicates an error with your database name java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs!

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution didn't work then another way you can try is by putting -

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.package.class", "com.package.anotherClass"})
```

in your main application class.

This will scan all your classes present inside the packages.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was using in the `application.properties` the following configuration line:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

I just removed the line and everything works fine again.